# Handling error Pages in Struts 2

Tags: http, exception, error-handling, struts2, struts

Whenever I enter the URL localhost:8443/context/anyname.anyextension I get the Status 404 (Not found) But when I try something like localhost:8443/context/anynameWithouthExtensions it seems that Struts 2 tries to map to an action and then I get the error 500 (Internal Server Error). Shouldn't I always get the status 404 with both approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably used a  `<default-action-ref` , that is a reference to the default Action to be used for all the UN-matched requests for *that* namespace.
And for that namespace, you have some rules specifying that only URLs without extensions
are handled.

Take a look at this:

Docs: http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/action-configuration.html

```
<package name="Hello" extends="action-default">

    <default-action-ref name="UnderConstruction">

    <action name="UnderConstruction">
        <result>/UnderConstruction.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

and eventually post your configuration.

If this is the case, i expect you got 404 even with a

```
localhost:8443/context/SOME_INVENTED_PATH/anynameWithouthExtensions
```

because the default action ref is probably bound only to the root.

AND the default Action goes on error, of course...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a result of how Struts 2 attempts to map URLs to actions.  When you provide the ".anyextension", in knows it is not a valid Struts 2 action, unless you were to append ".action" as the extension (which is the default extension used by Struts 2).  Any other, and it knows that it's not a Struts 2 call.  Likewise, I believe the lack of an extension is a default for Struts 2 and it tries to lookup the action, and it fails because there is no valid action.

You can add custom extensions by adding this to your struts.xml:

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=",action,do" />
```

Additionally, you could add some error handler to Struts to return 404 codes in the case of a valid action, but that would fall under a different question.

Thanks,
Andy